# SimpleOnGestureListener not working for ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, gesture

I have a screen where I have a header, a TextView inside a ScrollView and footer. I have to use ScrollView as the Text in the TextView can be long also.

Now when I am using SimpleOnGestureListener for this screen. It is not working for the ScrollView section. Removing the ScrollView everything working fine. But for the case of long text, some text are getting missed.

I want to use onFling and onDoubleTap in SimpleOnGestureListener.

Please advise.

Regards,
Shankar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a custom ScrollView object and override it's onTouchEvents to also check for your gestures. It's demonstrated in the following code.

```
public class GestureScrollView extends ScrollView {
    GestureDetector myGesture;

    public GestureScrollView(Context context, GestureDetector gest) {
        super(context);
        myGesture = gest;
    }

    public GestureScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public GestureScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (myGesture.onTouchEvent(ev))
            return true;
        else
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (myGesture.onTouchEvent(ev))
            return true;
        else
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you run into any issues. :)

-Zaid

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

But how would I pass the pass my GestureDetector to this custom ScrollView class.

Comment: You can make you GestureDetector a global variable or you can add another constructor with a GestureDetector as an argument and a local variable. I edited the code to show how to make the other constructor.

Comment: Thanks . Facing nullpointerexception in the onTouchEvent method for myGesture object. I am passing the gesture object as follows from my Activity class: 
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
        gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        scrollV = new GestureScrollView(getApplicationContext(), gestureDetector);
Please advise

Comment: Try gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(gestureListener);

Comment: Hey, Thanks again for the reply. Still I am not able to fix the issue. Could you give me your mail Id, so that I can send you the project. Probably I am missing something in the code.

Comment: me too getting NullPointerException. Was anybody able to resolve thiss?

Answer (score 14):

I got the solution for this issu

Add following method in the your Activity class

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

As suggested in the below link:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9fdfb03d0959e299

Comment: Much easier than messing around with the ScrollView implementation, thanks man!